# Foreach Checked and click event knockout

Tags: asp.net-mvc, knockout.js, data-binding, checked

I would like to add the values of 'Cost' based on checkbox checked event on knock out.

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: $root.searchedResults">
    <!-- ko if: Id-->
    <tr>
        <td data-bind="text: Id"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: Cost"></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: $root.searchedResults().length > 0, click: $root.Hospital_click"></td>
    </tr>
    <!-- /ko -->
</tbody>
```

And the sum of cost should be displayed in

```
<div data-bind="text: ko.toJSON(SumofItems)"></div>
```

The click event is not updating my sum based selection. Can someone help?

```
self.Hospital_click = function () {
    //Suggest
}
```

My View  model is:

```
var SearchModel = function () {

    var self = this;
    self.searchFromDate = ko.observable('01/01/2014');
    self.searchToDate = ko.observable('01/01/2016');

    self.searchedResults = ko.observableArray([]);

    self.search = function () {


        var model = {
            BeginDate: self.searchFromDate(),
            EndDate: self.searchToDate()
        };

        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("SearchSpend", "Analysis", new { Area = "Portal" })',
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            dataType: "json",
            data: ko.toJSON(model),

            success: function (response) {
                self.searchedResults(response);

            }
        });

    };
```

Comment: show your view model

Comment: Provided my View model @HakamFostok

Answer (score 1):

You could add a new observableArray with the id's of the selected results (`selectedResults`).  The viewmodel could be:

```
    function Result(id,cost) {
        this.Id = id;
        this.Cost = cost;
    }

    function viewModel() {

        var self = this;

        self.searchedResults = ko.observableArray([]);

        self.selectedResults = ko.observableArray([])

        self.totalCost = ko.computed(function() {
            let total = 0;
            for(let p = 0; p < self.searchedResults().length; ++p)
            {
                if (self.selectedResults.indexOf(self.searchedResults()[p].Id)>=0){
                    total += self.searchedResults()[p].Cost;
                }
            }
            return total;
        });

    };
```

`totalCost` will return the sum of the `Cost` field for all selected results.

And the view could be something like this:

```
    <table data-bind="foreach: searchedResults">
        <tr>
            <td data-bind="text: Id"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: Cost"></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" value="" data-bind="checkedValue: Id, checked: $parent.selectedResults"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <div data-bind="text: totalCost"></div>
```

`totalCost` is a computed value that returns de sum of the `Cost` for only the selected results.

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j3t7fa9c/3/).

In the fiddle, the data comes from the array `listOfResults`.  In your case, this comes from the `success` function (Ajax request); in this function you also needs to clean the `selectedResults`.